SwiftUI blur bottom bar still showing
I have created an app with a custom nav bar. This is working well but I still have a blur bottom bard showing up that I cannot remove.
The code below is the view:
var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                TabView(selection: $activeTab) {
                    FeedView(showNavBar: $showNavBar)
                        .onAppear {
                            activeTab = .home
                        }
                        .background {
                            if !isTabBarHidden {
                                HideTabBar {
                                    isTabBarHidden = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .tag(TabModel.home)
                    
                    SearchView()
                        .onAppear {
                            activeTab = .search
                        }
                        .tag(TabModel.search)
                    
                    UnderDevelopmentView(title: "MyCookBook")
                        .onAppear {
                            activeTab = .cookbook
                        }
                        .tag(TabModel.cookbook)
                    
                    CurrentUserProfileView()
                        .onAppear {
                            activeTab = .profile
                        }
                        .tag(TabModel.profile)
                }
                if(showNavBar) {
                    NavBarView(activeTab: $activeTab)
                }
            }

        }
    }


Any idea how to remove this blur bar ?
Thanks

You can hide the .tabBar or the .bottomBar with the following modifier:
.toolbar(.hidden, for: .tabBar) <- iOS 16

.toolbarVisibility(.hidden, for: .tabBar) <- iOS 18

